# How to trigger cloud Function when Build Successful in CircleCI

Tags: circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I’m looking for a way to trigger a cloud function (HTTP Trigger) when the CircleCI is job success? I want to post an artifact URL for the cloud function when the circle-ci job success (this is for an android project)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `when: on_success` function to determine when the job step will run. More information on that here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run

As for the HTTP Trigger, you can run any bash file or command from the command output. Here's what it might look like.

```
- run:
    command: |
      echo Hitting endpoint
      curl mywebsite.com
    when: on_success
```

Comment: Thanks, @scott, I'll give a try with this,